# Moderator Election Process questions

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

Q1: What is expected term of service for a moderator?

Q2: If one were at risk of being completely offline the week of July 21, does this hamper one's election chances?

Answer (score 6):

Moderators are elected to serve until they choose to step down. It's up to them to decide how long to serve. It's completely voluntary and you are encouraged to take breaks and to step down if it ever becomes a burden.

The timeline for the election is as follows:

- Nomination phase today - 7/19 20:00 UTC
- Primary phrase 7/19 20:00 UTC - 7/23 20:00 UTC
- Election phase 7/23 20:00 UTC - 7/30 20:00 UTC

This means that if you were going to be offline for the week of 7/21 you'd miss the end of the primary phase and most of the election. However, this basically only hampers your ability to participate in any candidate chats that might happen, you won't miss the opportunity to respond to comments on your nomination or answer question on meta (as that will be open the entire election period, maybe even the entire primary period as well, not sure on that).

Comment: Hmm... I was under the misunderstanding that moderators served a 1 year term.  That's not the case?  It's  until they decide to recluse themselves, or [are removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)?  In the words of Mater.. Dadgum!

Comment: @DavidStratton it's a common misconception, but no, the only time a current moderator must stand for election is at the end of beta.